# Create Users for logged in Admin users

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-middleware

I wanted to give option to create users for Admin without using Registration form.

Do I need to change existing methods and forms ? How do I store password with encryption same as in default registration option. what is the best way to do it?

UserController class is already created using

> php artisan make:controller PhotoController

```
class UserController extends Controller {
    public function create()
    {
         $users = User::get();
         return view('user.index', compact('users'));       
    }
    public function store()
    {
         $input = Request::all();
         ........
    }
}
```

Comment: Imo the best option is to have a flag is_admin (or a bunch of roles) in the database. After registration you could manually update your user with setting is_admin = true.
In case you really need to create 'em without a registration form you can write a command for it.

Comment: can i use below class to do that. can i override these methods, what is the best practice for laravel 5.
Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;
Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Registrar;
Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

Comment: `Hash::make($password)`